# Write in NetCDF as a variable as a function of time

Tags: fortran, fortran90, netcdf

I'm trying to modify a Fortran 90 code which writes a 2D array to the output in a NetCDF classic format. I would like the variable to have an extra dimension for time (i.e., it will be a 3D variable), printing it every corresponding time step during integration time of the model.

I'm not sure how it is being done; I appreciate any suggestion for doing it as efficiently as possible (also in a minimum file size).

```
subroutine writenetcdffile(array,argtitle)
    use netcdf
    implicit none
    real, intent(IN), dimension(:,:) :: array
    character*(*),intent(IN) :: argtitle 

    integer :: file_id, xdim_id, ydim_id
    integer :: array_id
    integer, dimension(2) :: arrdims
!    character(len=*) :: argtitle = Flag_in

    integer :: i, j
    integer :: ierr

    i = size(array,1)
    j = size(array,2)

    ! create the file
    ierr = nf90_create(path='test.nc', cmode=NF90_CLOBBER, ncid=file_id)

    ! define the dimensions
    ierr = nf90_def_dim(file_id, 'X', i, xdim_id)
    ierr = nf90_def_dim(file_id, 'Y', j, ydim_id)

    ! now that the dimensions are defined, we can define variables on them,...
    arrdims = (/ xdim_id, ydim_id /)
    ierr = nf90_def_var(file_id, 'Array',  NF90_REAL, arrdims, array_id)

    ! ...and assign units to them as an attribute 
    ierr = nf90_put_att(file_id, array_id, "title", argtitle)

    ! done defining
    ierr = nf90_enddef(file_id)

    ! Write out the values
    ierr = nf90_put_var(file_id, array_id, array)

    ! close; done
    ierr = nf90_close(file_id)
    return
  end subroutine writenetcdffile

MODULE Module_NetCDF

 use netcdf
 IMPLICIT NONE

 integer :: file_id, xdim_id, ydim_id, tdim_id
 integer :: array_id(5)
 integer, dimension(3) :: arrdims

 integer :: i, j
 integer :: ierr

 CONTAINS

SUBROUTINE NetCDF_Init(ICase)

   IMPLICIT NONE

   INTEGER :: ICase

   SELECT CASE(ICase)
   Case(1)
       ! create the file
        ierr = nf90_create(path='test.nc', cmode = NF90_CLOBBER, ncid = file_id)
   Case(2)
       ! Reopen the file for writing
       ierr = nf90_open(path = "test.nc", mode = nf90_write, ncid = file_id)
       if (ierr /= nf90_noerr) call check(ierr)
   Case(3)
        ! close; done
        ierr = nf90_close(file_id)
   END SELECT

   RETURN
   END SUBROUTINE NetCDF_Init


    SUBROUTINE NetCDF_Def(Array,ArrayTitle,ArrayUnits)

   IMPLICIT NONE

   real, intent(IN), dimension(:,:) :: Array
   character(*),intent(IN) :: ArrayTitle(5)
   character(*),intent(IN) :: ArrayUnits(5)  

! Locals 
   integer :: k

   i = size(Array,1)
   j = size(Array,2)

!   CALL NetCDF_Init(1)

    ! define the dimensions
    ierr = nf90_def_dim(file_id, 'X', i, xdim_id)
    ierr = nf90_def_dim(file_id, 'Y', j, ydim_id)
    ierr = nf90_def_dim(file_id, 'Time', nf90_unlimited, tdim_id)

    ! now that the dimensions are defined, we can define variables on them,...
    arrdims = (/ xdim_id, ydim_id, tdim_id /)
    do k = 1,size(ArrayTitle)
       ierr = nf90_def_var(file_id, ArrayTitle(k),  NF90_REAL, arrdims, array_id(k))

    ! ...and assign units to them as an attribute 
       ierr = nf90_put_att(file_id, array_id(k), "Units", ArrayUnits(k))
    enddo

    ! done defining
    ierr = nf90_enddef(file_id)

   RETURN
   END SUBROUTINE NetCDF_Def
SUBROUTINE NetCDF_Write(Array,FlagTitle,NTime)

   IMPLICIT NONE

   real, intent(IN), dimension(:,:) :: Array
   integer,intent(IN) :: NTime
   character(*),intent(in) :: FlagTitle

! Locals
   integer :: J_id

   IF(FlagTitle.EQ.'ONECOND')THEN
      J_id = 1
   ELSEIF(FlagTitle.EQ.'MELTING')THEN
      J_id = 2  
   ELSEIF(FlagTitle.EQ.'FREEZ_NEW')THEN
      J_id = 3
   ELSEIF(FlagTitle.EQ.'TFREEZ')THEN
      J_id = 4
   ELSEIF(FlagTitle.EQ.'DFREEZ')THEN
      J_id = 5     
   ENDIF

   CALL NetCDF_Init(2)

   ierr = nf90_put_var(file_id, array_id(j_id), Array, start=[1,1,ntime], count=[i,j,1])

   CALL NetCDF_Init(3)


   RETURN
   END SUBROUTINE
SUBROUTINE check(status)

   IMPLICIT NONE 
   integer, intent ( in) :: status

    IF(status /= nf90_noerr) THEN 
       PRINT *, trim(nf90_strerror(status))
       STOP 2
    ENDIF
  END SUBROUTINE check  

 END MODULE Module_NetCDF
```

Comment: The routine you gave is for a 2D array... What did you try for 3D arrays? What error(s) do you get? As it is now, your question is *too broad*!

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is define the time dimension of `nf90_unlimited` length. This will allow you to write a 2-d array one slice at a time into a 3-d array, and makes the length of this array unspecified. Use `start` and `count` optional dummy arguments to a `nf90_put_var` call to specify where to write the 2-d slice.

```
! create the file
ierr = nf90_create(path='test.nc', cmode=NF90_CLOBBER, ncid=file_id)

! define the dimensions
ierr = nf90_def_dim(file_id, 'X', i, xdim_id)
ierr = nf90_def_dim(file_id, 'Y', j, ydim_id)
ierr = nf90_def_dim(file_id, 'Time', nf90_unlimited, tdim_id)

! now that the dimensions are defined, we can define variables on them,...
arrdims = (/ xdim_id, ydim_id, tdim_id /)
ierr = nf90_def_var(file_id, 'Array',  NF90_REAL, arrdims, array_id)

! done defining
ierr = nf90_enddef(file_id)

! Time loop
do n = 1,nm

  ! Calculations go here

  ! Write out the values      
  ierr = nf90_put_var(file_id, array_id, array, start=[1,1,n], count=[i,j,1])

enddo
```

What I do in most of my programs is create the file and define dimensions and variables at the beginning, and write the fields in a loop afterward. If your simulations take a long time and you want to be able to look at the output during the simulation in progress, do the open/write/close steps inside of the model solver do-loop.

Comment: Thanks @milancurcic. This is exactly what I needed, I'll give it a try. In NetCDFIf, if I want to watch the output during run-time, do I must close the file before analyzing it with, say, MATLAB ?

Comment: BTW - which Call command corresponds to OPEN the file each time for 'nf90_put_var' call ? (I assume I shouldn't use 'nf90_create' repeatably).

Comment: @Jacob Use `nf90_open` and `nf90_close` to open and close files, respectively. I believe that you need to close the file in order to read it, however, I noticed that ncview can read the NetCDF files while they are being in the open state and being written to. Give it a try. Also, look up Fortran NetCDF User Guide online. It is very useful.

Comment: @milancurcuc - Thanks for your help. I have wrote a module (Module_NetCDF) for the benefit of future users inquiries.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your example. Was *super* useful. Trying to get my model to print out netcdf results.